# How to write a bash script which automate entering "docker container" and doing other things?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I want to implement an automatic `bash` script which enters a running `docker container`, and do some stuffs:

```
# cat docker.sh
#!/bin/bash -x

docker exec -it hammerdb_net8 bash
cd /data/oracle/tablespaces/
pwd
```

Executing the script on terminal:

```
# ./docker.sh
+ docker exec -it hammerdb_net8 bash
[root@npar1 /]#
```

The output shows only login the `docker container`, but won't do other operations.

Is there any method to automate entering `docker container` and doing other things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bash -c`:

```
docker exec -it hammerdb_net8 bash -c 'cd /data/oracle/tablespaces/; pwd; ls'
```

For running a series of commands use [here-doc in BASH](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
docker exec -i hammerdb_net8 bash <<'EOF'
cd /data/oracle/tablespaces/
pwd
ls
EOF
```

Comment: Is there any difference between "`docker ... bash <<'EOF'`" and "`docker ... bash <<EOF`"?

Comment: Using `'EOF'` makes all the lines not subjected to parameter expansion so e.g. you can use `p=$PWD` and `$PWD` will not be expanded in current shell.

Comment: Could you give an example?